# Extracting data from Google Play web site

Tags: web-crawler, google-play

I have a few apps up at Google play. Now when I log in I am able to see statistics like **Total User Installs** and **Active User Installs**. I can manually check these figures, but is there a way I can write a code to extract this data automatically by using my log in credentials?

I tried using a third party tool with Java called Jsoup, but google does not seem to allow any such tools access any information it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is an official Google Play Android Developer API but it is fairly limited in what it can do. Refer to : https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/

Additionally, there is an unofficial API: http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/ which does more but don't think it has enough to do what you want to extract.

For more information, refer to the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661434/does-google-play-have-an-api